# How does Pytorch's "Fold" and "Unfold" work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I've gone through the [official doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Fold.html). I'm having a hard time understanding what this function is used for and how it works. Can someone explain this in layman's terms?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The [`unfold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=unfold#torch.nn.functional.unfold) and [`fold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.fold) are used to facilitate "sliding window" operations (like convolutions). Suppose you want to apply a function `foo` to every `5x5` window in a feature map/image:

```
from torch.nn import functional as f
windows = f.unfold(x, kernel_size=5)
```

Now `windows` has `size` of batch-(5*5*`x.size(1)`)-num_windows, you can apply `foo` on `windows`:

```
processed = foo(windows)
```

Now you need to "fold" `processed` back to the original size of `x`:

```
out = f.fold(processed, x.shape[-2:], kernel_size=5)
```

You need to take care of `padding`, and `kernel_size` that may affect your ability to "fold" back `processed` to the size of `x`. Moreover, `fold` *sums* over overlapping elements, so you might want to divide the output of `fold` by patch size.

---

Please note that [`torch.unfold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.unfold.html) performs a different operation than `nn.Unfold`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73276874/1714410) for details.

Answer (score 68):

`unfold` imagines a tensor as a longer tensor with repeated columns/rows of values 'folded' on top of each other, which is then "unfolded":

- `size` determines how large the folds are
- `step` determines how often it is folded

E.g. for a 2x5 tensor, unfolding it with `step=1`, and patch `size=2` across `dim=1`:

```py
x = torch.tensor([[1,2,3,4,5],
                  [6,7,8,9,10]])
```

```py
>>> x.unfold(1,2,1)
tensor([[[ 1,  2], [ 2,  3], [ 3,  4], [ 4,  5]],
        [[ 6,  7], [ 7,  8], [ 8,  9], [ 9, 10]]])
```

[image]

`fold` is roughly the opposite of this operation, but "overlapping" values are summed in the output.

Comment: Your drawing made the penny drop for me! Thank you!

Comment: An important point about "fold" and "unfold" is that the memory isn't copied. This makes them very fast. But also note that if you change the "2" entry in your unfolded array, both 2s will change, and so will the original 2 in x.

Answer (score 26):

### One dimensional unfolding is easy:

```
x = torch.arange(1, 9).float()
print(x)
# dimension, size, step
print(x.unfold(0, 2, 1))
print(x.unfold(0, 3, 2))
```

Out:

```
tensor([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8.])
tensor([[1., 2.],
        [2., 3.],
        [3., 4.],
        [4., 5.],
        [5., 6.],
        [6., 7.],
        [7., 8.]])
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [3., 4., 5.],
        [5., 6., 7.]])
```

### Two dimensional unfolding (also called *patching*)

```py
import torch
patch=(3,3)
x=torch.arange(16).float()
print(x, x.shape)
x2d = x.reshape(1,1,4,4)
print(x2d, x2d.shape)
h,w = patch
c=x2d.size(1)
print(c) # channels
# unfold(dimension, size, step)
r = x2d.unfold(2,h,1).unfold(3,w,1).transpose(1,3).reshape(-1, c, h, w)
print(r.shape)
print(r) # result
```

```
tensor([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.,
        14., 15.]) torch.Size([16])
tensor([[[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
          [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  7.],
          [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.],
          [12., 13., 14., 15.]]]]) torch.Size([1, 1, 4, 4])
1
torch.Size([4, 1, 3, 3])

tensor([[[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
          [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
          [ 8.,  9., 10.]]],


        [[[ 4.,  5.,  6.],
          [ 8.,  9., 10.],
          [12., 13., 14.]]],


        [[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
          [ 5.,  6.,  7.],
          [ 9., 10., 11.]]],


        [[[ 5.,  6.,  7.],
          [ 9., 10., 11.],
          [13., 14., 15.]]]])
```

[image: patching]

Comment: Can you add the corresponding `.fold` operations to return to the original tensor?

Comment: Check the [fold example](https://programming-review.com/pytorch/tensor#tensor-fold-and-unfold)

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to get the same result with a single `F.unfold()` call by doing something like `F.unfold(input=x2d, kernel_size=(3, 3), dilation=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), padding=(0, 0)`?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no answers with 4-D tensors and nn.functional.unfold() only accepts 4-D tensor, I will would to explain this.

Assuming the input tensor is of shape `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`, and I have taken an example where `batch_size = 1, channels = 2, height = 3, width = 3`.

[image]

`kernel_size = 2` which is nothing but a 2x2 kernel

[image]