# How can I combine and overlap two tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two tensors that should together overlap each other to form a larger tensor. To illustrate:

```
a = torch.Tensor([[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])
b = torch.Tensor([[5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7]])

a = [[1 2 3]    b = [[5 6 7]
     [1 2 3]]        [5 6 7]]
```

I want to combine the two tensors and have them partially overlap by a single column, with the average being taken for those elements that overlap.

e.g.

```
result = [[1 2 4 6 7]
          [1 2 4 6 7]]
```

The first two columns are the first two columns of  'a'. The last two columns are the last two columns of 'b'. The middle column is the average of 'a's last column and 'b's first column.

I know how to merge two tensors side by side or in a new dimension. But doing this eludes me.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what do you mean by partial overlap? the example you have given is not completely obvious. E.g. the  result has dimension `2x5` from combination of two tensor of dimensions `2x3` is not very natural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a trivial operation, and this solution is not very trivial or intuitive either.

Looking at `result` with shape=`(2, 5)`, you can think of `a` and `b` as two `2x3` patches of `result` taken with `stride=2`. Like this illustration:
[image]

We can use pytorch's [`unfold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/nn.html#unfold) to "recover" the green (`a`) and blue (`b`) patches from `result` ("recover" up to the averaged values):

```py
from torch.nn import functional as nnf

recovered = nnf.unfold(result, kernel_size=(2,3), stride=2)
```

The result is:

> ```
> tensor([[[1., 4.],
>          [2., 6.],
>          [4., 7.],
>          [1., 4.],
>          [2., 6.],
>          [4., 7.]]])
> ```

The patches were recovered (as column vectors).

Now that we understand how to get `a` and `b` from `result`, we can use [`fold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.1.0/nn.html#fold) to perform the "inverse" operation and go from `b` and `b` to `result`.
First, we need to flatten concatenate `a` and `b` to the shape `fold` expects (mimicking the output of `unfold`, two "flatten" patches of 3x2 elements):

```py
uf = torch.cat((a.view(1, 6, 1), b.view(1, 6, 1)), dim=2)
```

We can now "fold" the patches

```py
raw = nnf.fold(uf, (2,5), kernel_size=(2,3), stride=2)
```

We are not there yet, when there are overlapping elements `fold` [sums up](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972525/1714410) the overlapping elements, resulting with

> ```
> tensor([[[[1., 2., 8., 6., 7.],
>           [1., 2., 8., 6., 7.]]]])
> ```

To count how many elements were summed for each entry in result, we can simply "fold" an all ones tensor

```py
counter = nnf.fold(torch.ones_like(uf), (2, 5), kernel_size=(2, 3), stride=2)
```

And finally, we can recover `result`:

```py
result = raw / counter
```

> ```
> tensor([[[[1., 2., 4., 6., 7.],
>           [1., 2., 4., 6., 7.]]]])
> ```

Piece of cake.

Comment: I followed your first block of code to get `recovered`, then I already get `NotImplementedError: Input Error: Only 4D input Tensors are supported (got 2D)`. I am using PyTorch 1.6.0