# element-wise operation in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have two Tensors A and B, `A.shape` is (b,c,100,100), `B.shape` is (b,c,80,80),
how can I get tensor C with shape (b,c,21,21) subject to
`C[:, :, i, j] = torch.mean(A[:, :, i:i+80, j:j+80] - B)`?
I wonder whether there's an efficient way to solve this?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You should use an [average pool](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#avg-pool2d) to compute the sliding window mean operation.
It is easy to see that:

```py
mean(A[..., i:i+80, j:j+80] - B) = mean(A[..., i:i+80, j:j+80]) - mean(B)
```

Using [`avg_pool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#avg-pool2d):

```py
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

C = nnf.avg_pool2d(A, kernel_size=80, stride=1, padding=0) - torch.mean(B, dim=(2,3), keepdim=True)
```

---

If you are looking for a more general way of performing sliding window operations in PyTorch, you should look at [fold and unfold](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53972159/1714410).

Comment: Appreciate for your reply. This did solve my question. What if C subject to  C[:, :, i, j] = torch.mean(torch.pow(A[:, :, i:i+80, j:j+80] - B, 2))?

Comment: @HaoZhou Ha! This is a nice exercise! (I'll probably give it to my students...). Here's a hint: `(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2`. You already know how to handle the `a^2` and `b^2` parts. Think carefully what (very popular) operation can help you efficiently compute `ab`