# Shuffle patches in image batch

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, torchvision

I am trying to create a `transform` that shuffles the patches of each image in a batch.
I aim to use it in the same manner as the rest of the transformations in `torchvision`:

```
trans = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.CenterCrop(224),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5]),
            ShufflePatches(patch_size=(16,16)) # our new transform
        ])
```

More specifically, the input is a `BxCxHxW` tensor. I want to split each image in the batch into non-overlapping patches of size patch_size, shuffle them, and regroup into a single image.

Given the image (of size `224x224`):

[image]

Using `ShufflePatches(patch_size=(112,112))` I would like to produce the output image:

[image]

I think the solution has to do with `torch.unfold` and `torch.fold`, but didn't manage to get any further.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed [`unfold` and `fold`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972525/1714410) seem appropriate in this case.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

class ShufflePatches(object):
  def __init__(self, patch_size):
    self.ps = patch_size

  def __call__(self, x):
    # divide the batch of images into non-overlapping patches
    u = nnf.unfold(x, kernel_size=self.ps, stride=self.ps, padding=0)
    # permute the patches of each image in the batch
    pu = torch.cat([b_[:, torch.randperm(b_.shape[-1])][None,...] for b_ in u], dim=0)
    # fold the permuted patches back together
    f = nnf.fold(pu, x.shape[-2:], kernel_size=self.ps, stride=self.ps, padding=0)
    return f
```

Here's an example with patch size=16:
[image]

Comment: much faster than sklearn extract_patches_2d