# Is there a way to send patches of image into a transformer model for inference or combine the patches together to make one image?

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, computer-vision

I am making inference with a single image of size `224x224`  on a vision transformer model (deit). However, I divided the image into 196 patches and manipulated the pixels of one patch to check its behaviour. Each patch is of size `16x16`.

On feeding these patches to the model, I got the error: Input image size `(16*16)` doesn't match `(224*224)`. Of course the model was trained on `224x224` image and needs same size. An idea is to combine these patches together into one complete image but I am having problem in getting through.

The single image shape :([1, 3, 224, 224])
The divided-into-patches image shape: [196, 16, 16, 3]

```
import torch
from models.deit import deit_small_patch16_224
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
from torchvision.transforms import transforms as transforms
from torchvision.utils import make_grid

def into_patches(im, xPieces, yPieces):
    imgwidth, imgheight = im.size
    height = imgheight // yPieces
    width = imgwidth // xPieces
    #fig, axs = plt.subplots(yPieces, xPieces)
    img_list = []
    for i in range(0, yPieces):
        for j in range(0, xPieces):
            box = (j * width, i * height, (j + 1) * width, (i + 1) * height)
            a = im.crop(box)
            np_img = np.asarray(a)
            if i ==6 and j ==5:
                np_img.setflags(write=1)
                np_img[:] =0
            img_list.append(np_img)
    return img_list

class_names = ['plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']

model = deit_small_patch16_224(pretrained=True, use_top_n_heads=8, use_patch_outputs=False)

checkpoint = torch.load("./checkpoint/deit224.t7")
state_dict = checkpoint["model"]
new_state_dict = {}
for key in state_dict:
    new_key = '.'.join(key.split('.')[1:])
    new_state_dict[new_key] = state_dict[key]

model.head = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=model.head.in_features, out_features=10)
model.load_state_dict(new_state_dict)
model.eval()



img = Image.open("bird.jpeg")
img = img.resize((224, 224), resample=0)
a = np.array(into_patches(img, 14, 14))

img_tensor = torch.tensor(a)

# print(img_tensor.shape)
 with torch.no_grad():
     output = model(img_tensor)
     predicted_class = np.argmax(output)
     print(predicted_class.item())
```

I get the following error:-
AssertionError: Input image size `(16*3)` doesn't match model `(224*224)`.

Is there anyway to combine these 196 patches back into `224x224` image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`fold` and `unfold`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963266/1714410) to extract the patches, manipulate them and then re-arrange them back into an image:

```py
# divide the batch of images into non-overlapping patches
u = nnf.unfold(x, kernel_size=16, stride=16, padding=0)
# manipulate patch number 17
u[..., 17] = my_manipulation(u[..., 17])
# fold the patches back together
f = nnf.fold(u, x.shape[-2:], kernel_size=16, stride=16, padding=0)
```

Comment: It's doing exactly what I want and I can also notice the manipulated patch when I visualized it but how do I visualize the image as done in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962837/shuffle-patches-in-image-batch/66963266#66963266)