# Calculate variance with a kernel size in a tensor

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

Like what nn.Conv2d or nn.AvgPool2d do with a tensor and a kernel size, I would like to calculate the variances of a tensor with a kernel size. How can I achieve this? I guess maybe source code of pytorch should be touched?

Comment: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, without a [mre] this can't be answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only the variance you are after, you can use the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) that

```
var(x) = E[x^2] - E[x]^2
```

Using [`avg_pool2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#avg-pool2d) you can estimate the local average of `x` and of `x` squared:

```py
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

running_var = nnf.avg_pool2d(x**2, kernel_size=2, stride=1) - nnf.avg_pool2d(x, kernel_size=2,stride=1)**2
```

However, if you want a more general method of performing "sliding window" operations, you should become familiarized with [`unfold` and `fold`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972525/1714410):

```py
u = nnf.unfold(x, kernel_size=2, stride=1)  # get all kernel_size patches as vectors
running_var2 = torch.var(u, unbiased=False, dim=1)
# reshape back to original shape ("folding")
running_var2 = running_var2.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[2]-1, x.shape[3]-1)
```