# Easy way to convert a tensor shape In pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

**Input**

I have torch tensor as fallow.

The shape for this `input_tensor` is `torch.size([4,4])`

```
input_tensor = 
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

I'm going to create a tensor that stacks up the tensor that comes out of the above `input_tensor` by moving the Window in size (2,2).

**output**

my desired output is as follow

The shape for this `output_tensor` is `torch.size([8,2])`

```
output = 
tensor([[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [12, 13],
        [10, 11],
        [14, 15]])
```

My code is as follows.

```
x = torch.chunk(input_tensor, chunks=2, dim=0)
x = list(x)
for i, t in enumerate(x):
    x[i] = torch.cat(torch.chunk(t, chunks=2 ,dim=1))
output_tensor = torch.cat(x)
```

Is there a simpler or easier way to get the result I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `torch.split()` together with `torch.cat()` as follows:

```
output_tensor = torch.cat(torch.split(input_tensor, 2, dim=1))
```

The ouput with be:

```
output = 
tensor([[ 0,  1],
        [ 4,  5],
        [ 8,  9],
        [12, 13],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 6,  7],
        [10, 11],
        [14, 15]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at [`unfolding`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.unfold.html#torch.nn.functional.unfold) the tensor:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as nnf

input_tensor = torch.arange(16.).view(1, 1, 4, 4)
nnf.unfold(input_tensor, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0).T.reshape(8,2)
```

More on `unfolding` and `folding` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972525/1714410).