# Why is `nn.Unfold` not giving me the same results as `.unfold`

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Why is this giving me two completely different answers? And how can I get the same result as in approach 1, using approach 2?

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

kernel_size = 7
stride = 1

# approach 1
data = torch.rand(4, 64, 174, 120)
data1 = data.unfold(3, kernel_size * 2 + 1, stride)
print(data1.shape)

# approach 2
data = torch.rand(4, 64, 174, 120)
unfold = nn.Unfold(3, kernel_size * 2 + 1, stride)
data2 = unfold(data)
print(data2.shape)
```

Output:

```bash
torch.Size([4, 64, 174, 106, 15])
torch.Size([4, 576, 13432])
```

EDIT ------------------------------------------

I tried your approach @Shai. The shapes are the same, but the content is not. Any idea why?

```
import torch
from torch import nn

kernel_size = 7
stride = 1

# approach 1
data = torch.rand(4, 64, 174, 120)
data1 = data.unfold(3, kernel_size * 2 + 1, stride)
print(data1.shape)

# approach 2
data = torch.rand(4, 64, 174, 120)
b, c, h, w = data.shape
unfold = nn.Unfold(kernel_size=(1, 2*kernel_size + 1), dilation=1, stride=1, padding=0)
data2 = unfold(data.reshape(-1, 1, 1, w)).permute(0, 2, 1).reshape(b, c, h, -1, 2*kernel_size + 1)
print(data2.shape)

print(torch.equal(data1, data2))
```

Output:

```bash
torch.Size([4, 64, 174, 106, 15])
torch.Size([4, 64, 174, 106, 15])
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`torch.unfold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.unfold.html) "unfolds" along a certain dimension. In your example it takes 4x64x174 samples of dim 120 and extract all overlapping 15-windows, resulting with `data1` of shape 4x64x174x106x15.

In contrast, [`nn.Unfold`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unfold.html) works on `b`x`c`x`...` tensors and extract *spatial* patches. In your example, `nn.Unfold` got `kernel_size=3`, `dilation=kernel_size*2+1` and `padding=1`. Hence, it extracted 13,432 3x3 patches of 64 channels (3*3*64=576), resulting with `data2` of shape `4`x`576`x`13432`.

To get the same output of `torch.unfold` from `nn.Unfold` you need to reshape and permute:

```py
b, c, h, w = data.shape
unfold = nn.Unfold(kernel_size=(1, 2*kernel_size + 1), dilation=1, stride=1, padding=0)
data2 = unfold(data.reshape(-1, 1, 1, w)).permute(0, 2, 1).reshape(b, c, h, -1, 2*kernel_size + 1)
```

Please read **carefully** the doc of `nn.Unfold` as it works in a fundamentally different manner to `torch.unfold`. For more information about `nn.Unfold` and `nn.Fold` please see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972525/1714410).

Comment: Got it! For `dim=2` it should then be: `data2 = unfold(data.reshape(-1, 1, 1, h)).permute(0, 2, 1).reshape(b, c, -1, w, 2*kernel_size + 1)`

Comment: I tried you approach. The shapes are the same, but the content is not. Any idea why? @Shai

Comment: @MikelB my method is for unfolding the last dimension. if you want along a different dimension - it needs further editing

Comment: @MikelB for the exame you provided in yhe question (along last dimension): I tested my code and it performed as expected. Not only the shapes matched, but also the values.

Comment: I get False for torch.equal(data1, data2) for the last dimension, not the 2nd

Comment: @MikelB this is odd. I'll look into it tomorrow