# Slicing a tensor with tensor

Tags: pytorch

I want to make a tensor of moving window. I'm using a list comprehension, but, this is sequential making it extremely slow.

```
weight_list = [w[:, :, :, i : i + self.l_c] for i in range(n)]
```

I want to find

```
weight = torch.for_example.index_slice(w, start_indices=n, slice_length=self.l_c, dim=-1)
```

I've seen methods of "indexing". But not slicing. Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [unfolding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972525/1714410) of `w` with kernel size `(1, self.l_c)`.